# How to check for occurence of name in string?

Tags: string, lua, lua-patterns

I have a list of names separated by space in one variable like this:

```
blacklist = "name1 name2 name3 etc"
```

What I want is to check existing of some specified name in this list. Like

```
if nameInBlacklist("player_name") == true then
        dosomething()
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that the name you want to find is in the string `name`, you can use:

```
if (" " .. blacklist .. " "):find(" " .. name .. " ", 1, true) then
  -- do something
end
```

Note that the fourth parameter `true` is to turn off pattern matching facilities, so that it's OK for `name` to contain some special characters that need to escape.

If you need to use a function:

```
function nameInBlacklist(name)
  return (" " .. blacklist .. " "):find(" " .. name .. " ", 1, true)
end
```

Don't compare the return value with `true`, just use it as the condition directly:

```
if nameInBlacklist("player_name") then
  --do something
end
```

Answer (score 1):

If you had a long blacklist, you would convert it to a table keyed by the list entries. A short blacklist can easily be checked by string matching:

```
if (" "..blacklist.." "):find( " "..player_name.." ", 1, true ) then
    doSomething()
end
```

The last parameter to find turns on plain string matching for [find](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-string.find).